# How to separate a numpy array into separate columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like

```
  ID_0 ID_1  ID_2
0    a    b  0.05
1    a    b  0.10
2    a    b  0.19
3    a    c  0.25
4    a    c  0.40
5    a    c  0.65
6    a    c  0.71
7    d    c  0.95
8    d    c  1.00
```

I want to groupby and make a normalized histogram of the ID_2 column for each group. So I do

```
df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1']).apply(lambda x: np.histogram(x['ID_2'], range = (0,1), density=True)[0]).reset_index(name='ID_2')
```

However what I would really like is for the 11 elements of the numpy arrays to be in separate columns  of the dataframe.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can construct a series object from each numpy array and the elements will be broadcasted as columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df.groupby(['ID_0', 'ID_1']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(np.histogram(x['ID_2'], range = (0,1), density=True)[0])).reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: That's clever. Thank you!